# How to avoid undefined in object key with no value?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to iterate an object like this:

```
0: Object
appointments: Array[2]
unavailables: Array[2]
0: Object
1: Object
book_datetime: "2015-10-22 02:46:23"
data: "0"
end_datetime: "2015-10-22 13:00:00"
hash: null
id: "21"
id_google_calendar: null
id_services: null
id_users_customer: null
id_users_provider: "87"
is_unavailable: "1"
notes: "Nessuna"
resource_id: "0"
start_datetime: "2015-10-22 12:00:00"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
1: Object
appointments: Array[1]
unavailables: Array[0]
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

in this way:

```
$.each(response, function(_, obj) 
{
        $.each(obj, function(key, val) 
        {
                if (key === 'unavailables') 
                {
                        console.log("=> ", val[0]['id']);
                }
        });
});
```

Now all working fine but how you can see the second array contain `unavailables length = 0`, when the loop is on here I get

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

How can avoid this? There is a method that check if the current key has contain value or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably go for another check before accessing `val`:

```
if (key === 'unavailables' && val && val.length) 
{
    console.log("=> ", val[0]['id']);
}
```

Comment: Just another question: instead of val[0] is possible access to the actual key? Or I must use a variable count like for?

Comment: I think this should be another question, for which I would be glad to help, if I can.

Comment: I editted my comment above, you really should post another question imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. If `val[0]` doesn't exist, it will be replaced with an empty hash, that will respond to `['id']` with `undefined` (but avoid errors.)

```
(val[0] || {})['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if `val[0]['id'])` exists:

```
if (key === 'unavailables' && val[0]['id'])){

}
```

Comment: The fact of early accessing `val[0].id` here would hoist the error in the `if` condition, you need to first check that both `val` and `val[0]` are not `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `length` property of `val` as such

```
if (val.length > 0) {
   console.log("=> ", val[0]['id']);
} else {
   // contains no value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers work, but I'd like to point out the fact that your approach is not optimal: you iterate over all properties of all `obj`s.

In fact you don't need to do that; you can access the `unavailables` property directly. Your entire code could therefore be reduced to this:

```
$.each(response, function(_, obj) 
{
  var val = obj.unavailables;

  if (val && val[0]) {
    console.log("=> ", val[0].id);
  }
});
```